# Facebook iFrame is pulling rails dynamic pages as 404 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, http-status-code-404

I have a Facebook app page and a rails application. My rails application loads a dynamic page based on a key that is given. This works fine and dandy outside of my facebook app:

https://app.eventsent.net/event_lists/3d40ba2a4a10947c17c2337fba3421dd406cceb5?frame=true

However inside of Facebook the page is pulling up as a 404 error:

https://www.facebook.com/reynoldsdesignstudio/app_419134091467471

I have gotten around this issue by creating a static file within my system to be able to have facebook view it however this is not ideal as deploying the rails app with updates makes modifying these static pages a pain.

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got this figured out by changing the routes file to allow for a post request instead of just a get request

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to dynamic/static content. Also Facebook is showing a 501 error, not a 404. In short, your SSL cert is not valid for the staging.app subdomain you are pointing your Facebook page at.

Visiting your Facebook page (https://www.facebook.com/reynoldsdesignstudio/app_419134091467471) yields this error:

> #### This webpage is not available
>
> The webpage at **https://staging.app.eventsent.net/event_lists/3d40ba2a4a10947c17c2337fba3421dd406cceb5.html** might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>
> Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown error.

Note that the subdomain is *staging.app*. If you happen to be using Firefox, you get a nice error message the spells everything out:

> ## This Connection is Untrusted
>
> You have asked Firefox to connect securely to **staging.app.eventsent.net**, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure.
>
> staging.app.eventsent.net uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for the following names:
>       app.eventsent.net , www.app.eventsent.net
>
> (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

The easiest solution would be to get a WildCard SSL certificate that is valid for *.eventsent.net.

FYI, if you visit https://staging.app.eventsent.net/event_lists/3d40ba2a4a10947c17c2337fba3421dd406cceb5?frame=true, you will get a rather dire-looking warning from your browser. If you ignore the warning and tell the browser to accept the certificate, your Facebook page will then load fine in the same browser.